# Problem with PlayOnLinux and The Sims 4: "The program has encountered a serious problem and needs to be closed."

Tags: playonlinux

I have a serious problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Baver.
I try since yesterday to install The Sims 4 via PlayOnLinux.
It's not hard, but i have now a problem to launch the game:
I have try others versions of Wine, but the result is the even; 
The game this launch, and to the "EA" or "Maxis" logo, i see this message:
- "TS4.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to be closed."
How to fix the problem? :/
See you later, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I configured my wine to be windows XP and it worked. I had the same problem and it turned out it had been set to windows 7. So definitely try that. That being said, I know nothing about computers but I thought I'd share what worked for me.